# How to create a "max" dummy variables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, data.table

I want to create a "max" and a conditional dummy variable. Assume that I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
   Subject  Year    X   Ydummy
       A    1990    0   0
       A    1991    1   0
       A    1992    2   0
       A    1993    0   0
       A    1995    1   0
       A    1996    2   0
       A    1997    3   0
       B    1990    0   0
       B    1991    0   0
       B    1992    0   0
       B    1993    1   0
       B    1995    2   0
       B    1996    3   0
       B    1997    3   0
       C    1990    1   0
       C    1991    2   0
       C    1992    3   0
       C    1993    3   0
       C    1995    3   0
       C    1996    3   0
       C    1997    3   0
       C    1998    3   1
       D    1990    0   0
       D    1991    0   0
       D    1992    1   0
       D    1993    2   0
       D    1995    3   0
       D    1996    3   0
       D    1997    4   0
```

The X variable is a cumulative variable (measuring each Subject-Year).

**(1)** I want to create a set of "max" dummy variables: dummies that would indicate whether the X has reached max value 1,2,3, and so on. 
To simplify, let's say that I'm here interested in creating the variable *"Xmax3"*. 
The *"Xmax3"* indicates whether the X's max value is equal to 3 (for each Subject-Year). The *"Xmax3"* is 1 if the maximum X value is 3, and 0 otherwise.  The thing that makes it complicated is that I want it to be 1 only when the X turns 3 for the first time. Or the first time the max value is reached. See the example below.

I tried to create this variable using:

```
data$Xmax3 <- ave(data$X, data$Subject, FUN = function(x) if (max(x) == 3) 1 else 0)
```

But it doesn't control for 0's and for the fact that I want it only be 1 when the X turns 3.

**(2)** Based on *"Xmax3"* I want to generate a conditional dummy variable "*"Xmax3_noY"*. This variable should indicate whether the Y is 1 following 5 years after the X has reached its max value of 3. If Y is 1 following 5 years, then the "*"Xmax3_noY"* should be 0.

So if you look at the example below, you'll see that the *"Xmax3"* is 1 for `C – 1992`. But the "*"Xmax3_noY"* is 0 because the Y is 1 for `C – 1998` If the Y was 1 in 1999 (after 6 years) then the "*"Xmax3_noY"* woudl have been 1 as well.

Example (desirable outcome):

```
Subject     Year    X   Ydummy  Xmax3   Xmax3_noY
       A    1990    0      0      0        0
       A    1991    1      0      0        0
       A    1992    2      0      0        0
       A    1993    0      0      0        0
       A    1995    1      0      0        0
       A    1996    2      0      0        0
       A    1997    3      0      1        1
       B    1990    0      0      0        0
       B    1991    0      0      0        0
       B    1992    0      0      0        0
       B    1993    1      0      0        0
       B    1995    2      0      0        0
       B    1996    3      0      1        1
       B    1997    3      0      0        0
       C    1990    1      0      0        0
       C    1991    2      0      0        0
       C    1992    3      0      1        0
       C    1993    3      0      0        0
       C    1995    3      0      0        0
       C    1996    3      0      0        0
       C    1997    3      0      0        0
       C    1998    3      1      0        0
       D    1990    0      0      0        0
       D    1991    0      0      0        0
       D    1992    1      0      0        0
       D    1993    2      0      0        0
       D    1995    3      0      0        0
       D    1996    3      0      0        0
       D    1997    4      0      0        0
```

How would you create these two variables? I really appreciate any suggestions that are "pedagogical" (if possible), allowing me to experiment with different versions of these variables.

A reproducible sample:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 
    1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1990L, 1991L, 
    1992L, 1993L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
    1993L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L), X = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), Ydummy = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Subject", 
"Year", "X", "Ydummy"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

**EDIT ( after conversation with Steven Beaupré):**

The *Xmax3* variable should indicate when first max value of X is reached, that is when X has reached 3 in this case.

For the *Xmax3_noY* variable the condition is: if the Y ==1 in the following 5 years in the dataset after the X has reached max (and first) value 3, then the *Xmax3_noY* == 0. 
In other words,  `Xmax_noY == 1` if there isn't `Ydummy == 1` within `(Year +5)`

In addition, it would better to condition the *Xmax3_noY* variable as not only *after 5 years* but also *5 years before*. In other words: *The Xmax_noY == 1* if it isn't *Ydummy ==1* within the *(Year-5):(Year+5)*

Comment: Hi @StevenBeaupré 1) that's  correct, it isn't ==1 because it's not the first time the max value was reached. 2) Yes, that is the condition. I'll make it more clear now in the text as well.

Comment: On (1): `x$Xmax3 <- as.integer(x$X == max(x$X))`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré before I do that, I just saw something that's not correct. The  `Xmax_noY == 1` if there is *any*  `Ydummy ==1` within the `(Year-5):(Year+5)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(data) # or setDT to convert in place

dt[, Xmax3 := 0][X == 3, Xmax3 := c(1, rep(0, .N-1)), by = Subject][
                       , Xmax3 := if (max(X) > 3) 0, by = Subject]
dt[, Xmax3_noY := 0][X == 3,
                     Xmax3_noY := if(all(Ydummy[Year <= Year[1] + 6] == 0)) Xmax3 else 0,
                     by = Subject]
dt
#    Subject Year X Ydummy Xmax3 Xmax3_noY
# 1:       A 1990 0      0     0         0
# 2:       A 1991 1      0     0         0
# 3:       A 1992 2      0     0         0
# 4:       A 1993 0      0     0         0
# 5:       A 1995 1      0     0         0
# 6:       A 1996 2      0     0         0
# 7:       A 1997 3      0     1         1
# 8:       B 1990 0      0     0         0
# 9:       B 1991 0      0     0         0
#10:       B 1992 0      0     0         0
#11:       B 1993 1      0     0         0
#12:       B 1995 2      0     0         0
#13:       B 1996 3      0     1         1
#14:       B 1997 3      0     0         0
#15:       C 1990 1      0     0         0
#16:       C 1991 2      0     0         0
#17:       C 1992 3      0     1         0
#18:       C 1993 3      0     0         0
#19:       C 1995 3      0     0         0
#20:       C 1996 3      0     0         0
#21:       C 1997 3      0     0         0
#22:       C 1998 3      1     0         0
#23:       D 1990 0      0     0         0
#24:       D 1991 0      0     0         0
#25:       D 1992 1      0     0         0
#26:       D 1993 2      0     0         0
#27:       D 1995 3      0     0         0
#28:       D 1996 3      0     0         0
#29:       D 1997 4      0     0         0
#    Subject Year X Ydummy Xmax3 Xmax3_noY
```

Comment: dear eddi, thanks for this. The only problem with is that the max dummy is capturing all 3's in X. even when them value of the X is 4 or more See for ex. `D-1995` in your outcome, the `Xmax3` should not be ==1 because the max value there is 4 (see `D-1997)` . is it possible to make it that it would capture max values?

Comment: thanks again. I think that this is a right the answer but when I tried on the real the dataset it didn't work. The `Xmax3` did capture the X max value 3, but didn't control for the fact that there are gaps within each Subject. So for example Subject A has a gap in `1993`. Your code missed a lot of Subjects in the real data because X was ` 0,1,2,0,0, 1,2,3`.  So the last value 3 was not captured.

Comment: @FKG I don't understand what you mean. Please give an example of failure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that is going to generate the columns `Xmax_n` and `Xmax_n_noY` from 1 to 4 (8 new columns) and meet the following conditions:

- Indicate with `1` only the first max value of `X` within each `Subject` in the `Xmax_n` column
- Indicate with `0` the value of the `Xmax_n_noY` column for each `Xmax_n` value if there is a `Ydummy`value of `1` in the `Subject` group within a range of 5 years prior or after `Year`, otherwise, `1`

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Subject, X) %>%
  mutate(maxt   = ifelse(X != 0 & row_number(X) == 1, paste0("Xmax", X), NA),
         maxnoy = ifelse(!is.na(maxt), paste0("Xmax", X, "_noY"), NA),
         val    = ifelse(!is.na(maxt), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Y2  = ifelse(!is.na(maxnoy) & any(Ydummy == 1), Year[Ydummy == 1], NA),
         L   = ifelse(!is.na(maxnoy) & !is.na(Y2), Y2 %in% list((Year-5):(Year+5)), 1)) %>%
  spread(maxnoy, L, fill = 0) %>%
  spread(maxt, val, fill = 0)
```

---

In the first part, we `group_by()` `Subject` and `X` to generate three new columns of importance `maxt`, `val` and `maxnoy`

```
data %>%
  group_by(Subject, X) %>%
  mutate(maxt   = ifelse(X != 0 & row_number(X) == 1, paste0("Xmax", X), NA),
         maxnoy = ifelse(!is.na(maxt), paste0("Xmax", X, "_noY"), NA),
         val    = ifelse(!is.na(maxt), 1, 0)) %>%
```

Then we generate the fourth column of importance `L` which will take `0` for each `Xmax_n` if there is a `Ydummy` value of `1` in the `Subject` group within a range of 5 years prior or after `Year`, otherwise, `1`.

```
 group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Y2  = ifelse(!is.na(maxnoy) & any(Ydummy == 1), Year[Ydummy == 1], NA),
         L   = ifelse(!is.na(maxnoy) & !is.na(Y2), Y2 %in% list((Year-5):(Year+5)), 1)) %>%
```

Then we `spread()` the pair `maxt` & `val` and `maxnoy` & `L` to achieve the desired output format.

```
  spread(maxnoy, L, fill = 0) %>%
  spread(maxt, val, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Dear Steven, thanks for this. this code looks very advance to me. I did try it on the real dataset but wasn't able to check whether it does everything correct. For some reason, the code didn't  generate the variables. Note: In the real dataset the X, for some Subjects, can be up to 21 as highest.

Answer (score -1):

If your data is not to large you can use loops to solve the problem. This is often regarded as bad but you can transform the commands of the following loops easily into a function for that can be executed via `apply` (see. `?apply`.

SO, let us say that `data_size` is the length of your data i.e. `data_size <- dim(data)[1]` then you can calculated the column Xmax3 in two steps. First the following loop:

```
data$Xmax3 <- 0
for (t in 1:data_size) {
  if (data$X[t] == 3) {
    data$Xmax3[t] <- 1
  }
}
```

which can also be more elegantly expressed if you are willing to use dplyr:

```
data <- dplyr::mutate(data,Xmax3 = ifelse ((X == 3), 1 , 0))
```

Then in a second step we want to eliminate all the 1's that follow a 1. Again, there are multiple ways to achieve this. One possibility is to use the `diff(x)` function(see: `?diff`). It returns the difference between the values of `x`. E.g.: `diff(c(1,2,5,6,1))` will return '1 3 1 -5'. Note, that the returned vector is one shorter then the provided one, since the differences are taken. The then following part is then a bit clumsy, since`Xmax3_diff` we need to concatenate the first value of the `Xmax3` row back and remove all values below 0:

```
Xmax3_diff <- diff(data$Xmax3)
data$Xmax3 <- pmax( c(data$Xmax3[1],Xmax3_diff) , 0)
```

After this is done, the column `Xmax3_noY` can be obtained again with a loop. This time we have care about the last row-entries of the data!

```
buffer <- 5 # 5 because we want to check 5 years a head of the current time step
data$Xmax3_noY <- 0
for (t in 1:(data_size-buffer)) {
  # check if the the next 5 years of the Ydummy column are all 0
  test_for_followup_years <- any(data$Ydummy[t:(t+buffer)] == 0) 
  # If hte conditions we want are met, then set max3_noY to 1
  if ( (data$Xmax3[t] == 1) & test_for_followup_years ) {
    data$Xmax3_noY[t] <- 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I'll try it soon.

Comment: @FKG Hi. No Problem. But from your edit I just saw that I missunderstood the problem a little. Will revise my answer asap